# How do I add a non official database backend to Django?

Tags: database, django

It looks like Django's looking in the django/db/backends folder but when i install various adapters they install to /django itself - can I point to that? Copying them to the backends doesn't seem to work because it always says blablalb.base is missing...

Comment: Which database are you trying?

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#database-engine):

> You can use a database backend that doesn't ship with Django by setting 
>   DATABASE_ENGINE to a fully-qualified path (i.e. mypackage.backends.whatever).

So you can install the backend anywhere, as long as it is importable on your PYTHONPATH.  You just need to provide the full import path in DATABASE_ENGINE.